# css - Align centered image in list

Tags: jquery, html, css

I know what this question sounds like, like I want someone to feed me code because I'm too lazy to search. Well it's not.

I'm trying to make my menu look like this:
[image: What I want it to look like]
And I just can't seem to get that effect.

I want the image to be inline so the text doesn't hide behind it, but I want it to be dynamic - I want to make it so the image stays ordered even if I don't have 6 elements in my list, I want the image to always be there. Other than that the image pretty much describes what I want. All I got now is this:

Now here's what I got:
[image: what I got]
It's not what I want. It's not responsive like my example, where you may have 5 items (in different sizes is an option) but the image is still centered. How can I achieve that?

**EDIT:** I updated the code a little so now the blue ribbon bar is now really in the middle of the image. *Is there a better way of doing that instead of defining px.?*

**My code is hosted [here](http://nonamesldev.cf/test2.html)! Please check it out.**

Thanks in advance, NonameSL

Comment: Please supply an example of what you have tried.  The link is not sufficient enough.

Comment: what do you mean by "image stays ordered"? The image is always centered, but what happens to the list items is less clear… How "dynamic" are they? A few examples of the different use cases would go a long way…

Comment: The `li` should has a width and display type table-cell. Checkout [this](http://output.jsbin.com/lofisevoyo) without responsive.

Comment: @user1725382 How is the link not sufficient? I guess I'll include the source.

Comment: @sємsєм While this does do what I want, it doesn't work on different screen resizes, try to resize the page with your code and see what I mean. The list items are scrambled.

Comment: @NonameSL It is non responsive solution and I don't know specific one. However, you may try to set properties related to font size, padding, margins width and height using proportional units such as em or %

Answer (score 1):

You could use Flexbox if you want to vertically align the items too.

Pen: http://codepen.io/tomanagle/pen/zBgdAX

```
<nav>
<ul>
  <li>List item 1</li>
  <li>A quite longer list item</li>
  <li>An extremely long list item makes the logo un-centered.</li>
  <li><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f7/English_Pok%C3%A9mon_logo.svg
   "></li>
  <li>Shorter</li>
  <li>List</li>
  <li>Items</li>
</ul>
  </nav>
```

CSS:

```
nav > ul{
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

nav > ul > li{
  float: left;
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 12rem;
}
nav > ul > li > img{
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: This is nice but it doesn't work with list items with different sizes. See my pen: http://codepen.io/NonameSL/pen/OXKOoR/

Comment: That is easily fixed. Simply add width: 100% and a max-width to your list items. Don't forget to add a max-width: 100% to your img too. See the Codepen again: http://codepen.io/tomanagle/pen/zBgdAX

Answer (score 0):

make the following changes in you test2.html file on line number 26 i think of this file:

```
div#menu ul li a {
    background-color: #f8fad4;
    border-color: #136866;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
    border-style: solid;
    color: #555533;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;

    //new changes
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 120px;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I came up with this code which is quite similar. Added this to `div#menu ul li a`:

```
width:100px;
display: inline-block;
```

And if there's an odd number of list items just add a `visibility: hidden;` empty element to the smaller side.